# How to indent after access modifiers with clang-format

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

How can I realize the following indentation after access modifiers:

```
class A{
public:
int a;
}
```

should result in

```
class A
{
    public:
        int a; // note the indentation
}
```

clang-format only allows the access modifiers to be on the same level as the `int a` `AccessModifierOffset: 0` resulting in

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a;
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: VisualStudio 15 (unfortunately)

Comment: One way would be to set `IndentWidth` to 8 and `AccessModifierOffset` to `-4`. But this will also affect how statements within functions are indented. AFIK there's no clean way to do what you want here

Comment: I haven't found a way either, but it would be really nice, since this is the default in vim and my preferred style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto indent a c++ class with 4 spaces using clang-format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799183/how-to-auto-indent-a-c-class-with-4-spaces-using-clang-format)

Answer (score 6):

Where I work, we've stumbled upon the same problem. Since the `IndentWidth` parameter controls the indentation everywhere (classes, functions, etc.) what you're trying to achieve seems impossible. The next best thing, in my opinion, is to keep `IndentWidth=4` and set `AccessModifierOffset=-2`.
That way you get:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo() = default;
};

bool foo()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also `IndentAccessModifiers` should be set to `false`

Answer (score 5):

@Gabriel: as of `clang-format-13`, the boolean key `IndentAccessModifiers` is supported in your `.clang-format`.

You can achieve this for instance with:

```
UseTab: ForContinuationAndIndentation
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```

See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html for the complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved that with these settings:

```
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: 0
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```

If you are using a different `IndentWidth` have in mind that `AccessModifierOffset` stacks on top of that value.

Have in mind that `clang-format-13` or never is needed to use `IndentAccessModifiers` option.

Since there is no anchor, I can't link it directly, but you should read more about `IndentAccessModifiers` at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html