# How to auto indent a C++ class with 4 spaces using clang-format?

Tags: c++, indentation, auto-indent, clang-format

I got the next .clang-format file in my project's root directory:

```
---
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false
IndentWidth: 4
SortIncludes: false
NamespaceIndentation: All
...
```

Problem comes when I run clang-format on my c++ headers, the classes become autoindented like this:

[image]

As you can see, labels public & private are indented only with 2 spaces. But what I'm trying to achieve is the below output (indentation was manually tweaked):

[image]

That way code-collapsing becomes something really pleasant to do.

How could I tweak my .clang-format to achieve this effect? If not possible, how would you patch clang-format source code to achieve this desired behaviour?

EDIT:

I've tried using unsuccessfully AccessModifierOffset, I've used values {-2,0,2,4} example below:

[image]

As you can see the statement inside the public block won't be indented properly.

EDIT2:

I've tried the @Henrique Jung solution and that's definitely not what I'm asking for, if using that combination the result would be something like this one:

[image]

And as you can see, the content inside the functions are indented 8 spaces instead 4, which is not good.

EDIT3:

I gave a bounty few months ago so I'm going to try again as this one is definitely interesting. If I got enough knowledge about clang-format source code I'd give it a shot, unfortunately I don't.

Comment: try "AccessModifierOffset". This is a possible duplication of another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198963/how-can-i-tell-clang-format-to-indent-visibility-modifiers

Comment: @caoanan Not really, I had already tried AccessModifierOffset few days ago and for some reason it's not indenting properly the classes. While it's true that it will indent public/private/protected it's not indenting the statements below them. Please take a look to my question, I've put you an example

Comment: Eh, if only I could paste a screenshot [into this](http://clang-format.me/).  Seems you like the Webkit style settings.

Answer (score 10):

As near as I can tell, clang-format offers no option for indenting function contents differently from non-access-modifier class contents.  That is, consider the following code:

```
class A {
  public:
    void foo() {}
}

void bar() {
    int a;
}
```

In this code, the line "void foo() {}" will always be indented the same amount as "int a;" by clang-format.

The closest thing to the style you seem to want that is available would come from not indenting the access modifiers, e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
    void foo() {}
}

void bar() {
    int a;
}
```

This is done, for example, by the WebKit, Mozilla, and LLVM styles.  It's achieved by setting:

```
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you've already set `IndentWidth: 4` and based on the image where the indentation was manually tweaked, you need to add these to your .clang-format:

```
AccessModifierOffset: 0
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```

Have in mind that `clang-format-13` or never is needed to use `IndentAccessModifiers` option.

Since there is no anchor I can't link it directly, but you should read more about `IndentAccessModifiers` at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: This worked for me. I created `.clang-format` in the top-level directory of my project, and added `IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: 0
IndentAccessModifiers: true` (four settings across four lines, see original question and the parent answer; I cannot add newlines when writing a comment)

Comment: This works great, though the one annoying thing is this also indents parts with no access modifier

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve the effect you want by changing both **AccessModifierOffset** with **IndentWidth**. Basically, the first is used as an offset of the second, so if you create your *.clang-format* like this you get what you want:

```
AccessModifierOffset: -4
IndentWidth:     8
```

If `AccessModifierOffset` is 0, the `public` keyword would be at the same level of indentation as the members. However, changing `IndentWidth` will indent all code by 8 spaces, even those outside the class declaration. This is a sample code:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();
        virtual ~Foo(); };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's definitely not what i'm asking for, I've edited my answer to explain why... look the std::cout and return 0 statements, they're indented 8 spaces instead 4, I want 4.

Comment: Yeah I knew there was a side effect, however I couldn't find an specific indent variable for members.

Answer (score 1):

With `clang-format 13` (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-13.0.0) you can use:

```
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```

to achieve the desired behavior.

If you use default Visual Studio it comes with `clang-format 12` which doesn't support this feature. To use it download & install `clang-format 13` and from `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Code Style->Formatting->General` check `Use custom clang-format.exe file` and select `clang format 13` executable.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The newer version of `clang-format` starting from `13` and up is the solution to the original problem described by the question.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problems, and find the quickest solution is to make a copy of clang default setting(found by **Preference** -> **Package Settings** -> **Clang Format** -> **Custom Style-Default**) into the user custom setting(**Preference** -> **Package Settings** -> **Clang Format** -> **Custom Style - User**), then uncomment and modify some options into your own preference. For Example:

```
"ColumnLimit": 119,
// Indent width for line continuations.
"ContinuationIndentWidth": 4,
// The number of columns to use for indentation.
"IndentWidth": 4,
"TabWidth": 4,
"UseTab": "Never"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just to fomally answer the question. Using the newer `clang-format` version `13` and up, the configuration should be:

```
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false
IndentWidth: 4
IndentAccessModifiers: true
AccessModifierOffset: -4
SortIncludes: false
NamespaceIndentation: All
```