# How do I make clang to ignore the indentations during formatting?

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I have clang-format properly installed on my device. The Problem is whenever I format in my editor, I always get this:

```
int main() {

  printf("Hello world!");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My expected output is this:

```
int main() {

    printf("Hello world!");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, on my expected output, I wanted it to have an indentation (whenever I make curly braces), however on the output I get, the indentation gets reduced to two spaces per level.

I tried searching for solutions on YouTube, however I couldn't find one.

Comment: @Avi Berger, Not a great dupe, since one answer to the OP's question would be to use a `.clang-format`, and that can't be posted as an answer to the linked question.

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291835/631266)  @ikegami You're right. I was looking at another question that mentioned that, but also wasn't a good dupe and conflated them without noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default indentation in clang-format is likely set to 2 spaces, which is why you are seeing that in your formatted code. If you prefer 4 spaces of indentation, you need to change the **IndentWidth** setting in your *.clang-format* file.

Here is an example configuration that sets the indent width to 4 spaces:

```yaml
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
```

This tool comes in handy: https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried using the tool that you provided me, I was able to download the clang txt file, however I do not know on how or where would I put it?

Comment: @2leizy you should place `.clang-format` at the root directory of your project.

Comment: The mentioned configuration tool seems to not be updated anymore. This one https://clang-format-configurator.site/ seems to support more recent versions of clang-format.